# Press Double Back To Exit

Tags: android

Android Webview 
current code in my app works like this:
When user press back single time it will shows button asking "Do you want to quit?" shows yes or no options. when we select Yes it exit app and show interstitial ad. if you press No it will remains in the activity.

What I want is:
When user press back it will go to previous activity. If user double tap back button then it will ask for exit and if user select Yes. user will exit app and interstitial ad appears.

Please help me  to solve this issue.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private Fragment contentFragment;
String testDevice = "D0A04359EA1ECE9BA0CD4B6F457A9991";
String testDevice2 = "63C3530DA03C191310DB9AB8F0672E5C";
String testDevice3 = "801F2141A1DC3F743363AFDFDC42AF3A";
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private AdView mAdView;
boolean displayAd = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
    mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mainWebView.loadUrl(this.getString(R.string.channel_url));

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
    // Create an ad request. Check your logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
    // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(testDevice)
            .addTestDevice(testDevice2)
            .addTestDevice(testDevice3)
            .build();

    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            displayAd = true;
  //                View servername = findViewById(R.id.txt_List);
 //             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = 
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) servername.getLayoutParams();
//              layoutparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mAdView.getId());
//              layoutparams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
//              servername.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            if (!displayAd) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Proceed to the next level.
        }
    });

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

```
    // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId (defined in values/strings.xml).
    mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
    loadInterstitial();
}

private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

private InterstitialAd newInterstitialAd() {
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Proceed to the next level.
            finish();
            //goToNextLevel();
        }
    });
    return interstitialAd;
}

private void showInterstitial() {
    // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and reload the ad.
    if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();

    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void loadInterstitial() {
    // Disable the next level button and load the ad.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(testDevice)
            .addTestDevice(testDevice2)
            .addTestDevice(testDevice3)
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}


/*
 * We call super.onBackPressed(); when the stack entry count is > 0. if it
 * is instanceof EmpListFragment or if the stack entry count is == 0, then
 * we prompt the user whether to quit the app or not by displaying dialog.
 * In other words, from EmpListFragment on back press it quits the app.
 */

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    onShowQuitDialog();
}

public void onShowQuitDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    builder.setMessage("Do You Want To Quit?");
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    showInterstitial();
                }
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no `GestureDetector` for the back button, but one quick way is to start a timer when the user presses the back button and if there's a second tap before the timer runs out, then you consider that a double tap. Otherwise, it's a simple tap and you can finish your activity.

Comment: I have updated whole code above. Please check and suggest changes accordingly. so it will work fine with interstitial ad too.

Comment: on your single back press call your previous activity and exit on double back press as I have mentioned in answer please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847825/press-double-back-to-exit/46639761#46639761

Answer (score 5):

**This is the easiest code possible:**

```
private static final int TIME_DELAY = 2000;
private static long back_pressed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (back_pressed + TIME_DELAY > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;

       onShowQuitDialog();


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Comment: its showing cannot resolve symbol handler.I cant paste the whole main activity code because of text limitations. You have not included interstitial ad. please check and give me code with ads.

Comment: Please check the whole main activity code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6a1Wje6UpUXNDR0YVFfMkpyUTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated whole code above. Please check and suggest changes accordingly. so it will work fine with interstitial ad too.

Comment: Thank you Sir . Please  show the function  onShowQuitDialog.                             public void onShowQuitDialog()
    {
        Toast.makeText(DelegateListActivity.this, "Click again to exit app" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

Answer (score 1):

A temp flag will do the thing.
add this code in your onBackPressed() method.

```
boolean isSecond;

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (isSecond) {
        // Open your dialog here 
    }

    isSecond = true;
    new Handler() . postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            isSecond = false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: its showing cannot resolve symbol handler.I cant paste the whole main activity code because of text limitations. You have not included interstitial ad. please check and give me code with ads.

Comment: Please check the whole main activity code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6a1Wje6UpUXNDR0YVFfMkpyUTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated whole code above. Please check and suggest changes accordingly. so it will work fine with interstitial ad too.

Comment: Have a look here it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847825/press-double-back-to-exit/46639761#46639761

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
int backFlag = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

backFlag ++;

if(backflag == 1){
super.onBackPressed();
   // go to previous activity
}
else if(backFlag == 2){
   // ask user to exit
}

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        backFlag=0;                       
    }
}, 2000);
}
```

Comment: its showing cannot resolve symbol handler.I cant paste the whole main activity code because of text limitations. You have not included interstitial ad. please check and give me code with ads.

Comment: You have to import Handler class for it.

Comment: Please check the whole main activity code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6a1Wje6UpUXNDR0YVFfMkpyUTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have given the link where you can check the code. its showing errors & red lines. Please check my code and provide changes accordingly. I want the code like this. when user enters from activity A to B. if user press back button once then it will go to previous stage that is A. or if he double tap back button simultaneously then he will exit the app and interstitial ad appears.on the screen

Comment: I have updated whole code above. Please check and suggest changes accordingly. so it will work fine with interstitial ad too.

Comment: Need to replace the following code with your code. Am I right? Please check.@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    onShowQuitDialog();
}

Comment: Error:(166, 12) error: class MainActivity is already defined in package com.wAashiqeRasool.HamareNabi

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Can you update your code? Have you created another MainActivity class?

Comment: what is backflag. A parameter or local veriable?

Comment: It is a global variable.

Comment: I have done everything as mentioned in your reply. But still it's not working like tat I want. Still it ask for exit instead going back to previous stage when user press back button single time.

Comment: @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  onShowQuitDialog();
 } I replaced this with your code. And imported Handler by pressing Alt+Enter. After that all errors gone but in app it ask for exit when we click back button single time. It's not going to previously opened activity. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That is ok. But i want your full code to spot the error.

Comment: Here is the full code. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6a1Wje6UpUXaUphcXJPVjg3Tnc/view?usp=sharing Sorry for the delay.

Comment: remove int backFlag; after backFlag++;

Comment: Showing redline to backflag after removing that. I pressed Alt+Enter. It shows following options. Create local veritable, create field, create parameter, rename reference.

Comment: Flip '==' Insert App Indexing Code Negate '==' to '!=' Remove braces from if statement this are options with green icons.

Comment: Declare and Intialize backFlag below displayAd variable.

Comment: Unfortunately all this isn't working. Back button stops working after adding code. Thank you for your help. I will use my old code as new one is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function for double `onBackPressed()` so you have to construct your own version of it. The android system provides a `Handler` on which you can call `postDelayed` to measure the time between two and one click.

e.g. like this

```
boolean backPressed = false;
boolean backPressedTwice = false;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(!backPressed){
        backPressed = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!backPressedTwice)
            MainActivity.this.finish(); // go back to previous activity                      
        }
    }, 500);
}
if(backPressed) {
    // it's clicked twice
    backPressedTwice = true; // cancel the handler so it does not finish the activity
    onShowQuitDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: its showing cannot resolve symbol handler.I cant paste the whole main activity code because of text limitations. You have not included interstitial ad. please check and give me code with ads.

Comment: Please check the whole main activity code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6a1Wje6UpUXNDR0YVFfMkpyUTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated whole code above. Please check and suggest changes accordingly. so it will work fine with interstitial ad too.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo for your task:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    boolean ShowDialog = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!ShowDialog) {
            this.ShowDialog = true;
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);// time setting .. current is 2 sec
        } else {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            ShowDialog = false;
            ShowDailog();
        }
    }

    private void ShowDailog() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "show dialog here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ShowDialog = false;
            MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: its showing cannot resolve symbol handler.I cant paste the whole main activity code because of text limitations. You have not included interstitial ad. please check and give me code with ads.

Comment: Please check the whole main activity code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6a1Wje6UpUXNDR0YVFfMkpyUTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated whole code above. Please check and suggest changes accordingly. so it will work fine with interstitial ad too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
private long backPressedTime = 0;
private long backPressThreshold = 400;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable bacPressedRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MYActivity.super.onBackPressed();
    }
};

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(backPressedTime = 0){
       backPressedTime = Systemm.currentTimeInMillis();
       mHandler.postDelayed(bacPressedRunnable,backPressThreshold);
    }else if(System.currentTimeInMillis()-backPressedTime >=   backPressThreshold){
       mHandler.removeMessages(bacPressedRunnable);
       onShowQuitDialog();
    }else{
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
    backPressedTime = 0;
}
```

Comment: its showing cannot resolve symbol handler.I cant paste the whole main activity code because of text limitations. You have not included interstitial ad. please check and give me code with ads.

Comment: Please check the whole main activity code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6a1Wje6UpUXNDR0YVFfMkpyUTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated whole code above. Please check and suggest changes accordingly. so it will work fine with interstitial ad too.

Comment: Dear Nazarahmed, This is not a code sharing site, try to understand what you are coding and try to understand what this snippet does, and change according to your needs. If you have any doubt feel free to ask. Hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

**Exit android App on double back press use following updated code. It may solve your problem**

> ```
> private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce;
> ```

```
 private void onApplicationBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExit) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);
       return;
     }

    doubleBackToExit= true;

    Utilities_dialer.showToastMessage(this, "Press Again To Exit");
   //use your dialog box or toast message
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExit= false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. It may help you.

```
Boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(doubleBackToExitPressedOnce){
            // Do what ever you want
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        } else{
            // Do exit app or back press here
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

        }
```